# check if a block exists in another page or not with jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery code :

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var i = 1;
    j(document).ready(function(){
        j(".click").click(function(){
        i++;
        var toappend = 'test'+i+'.html' + ' .tester';
        j('.test').append(j('<div class="contain">').load(toappend).fadeIn('slow'));
  });

});
```

This code will go to test1.html file and get block with class .tester and will load it in .test class div

I want to get another pages block and show them in a page in click function

I need a condition that check if this block exists or not

Comment: `if(toappend` do you have some more to post?

Comment: sorry jai, my mistake, deleted now, see update

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need. You want to test if .test is empty?

Comment: additional discretion: first time we click on a div with class="click" this is what will be happen :
in page test2.html (i is 2 now) we have a div with class="tester" and it will append in a div in first page's div with class="test"
what i need is a condition to check that div in test2.html exists or not ?

Comment: just imagine this is a ajax loader, i just need first check if block does exists in that page or not, do u know such a jquery code ? (a code to check if a block exist in a html file or not) thx